# FitText.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webfonts, fittextjs

I'm trying to use FitText.js to resize the headlines to fit into the browser width.

In a few sections of my website the script works just fine, but on this page it's not doing the work for iPhone. It works fine on my Desktop though.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(".inner-title h2").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '12px', maxFontSize: '96px' });
```

Here's a screenshot.

http://imageshack.com/a/img713/6315/4myi.png

So the text should resize to fit the width of that red box.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, make sure you're not adding !important to your font size. I was doing that— to override the template I was using, and didn't think about it also overriding FitText.

Comment: I came here after searching for "js fittext not working". I got into the habit of using 0.6 for the compressor value and got great results. 
I added a new h3 today and used 0.6 for the compressor value. This new h3 would not fit the text no matter what I tried. 
When I went back to the default 1 compressor value it magically worked perfectly!